# How to delete some string in Python

Tags: python, json

```
import os
import sys
import time
import re
import json


from openpyxl import Workbook
from slackclient import SlackClient
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter



slack_client = SlackClient('token')
file = slack_client.api_call("users.list")

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(file , outfile, indent=2 )
```

I need to delete some useless info such as :images, status, emoji.But I really don't get it cuz not familiar with syntax.

So I need :

1. Find user info (skype, images and so on )
2. Delete it
3. Save it

I want to create a list of things which I need to delete and compare my list with json file.However  I run into an issue with code

P.S json file is  saved in Desktop folder

Comment: I don't use Slack, but have you just exposed an API key to us all? Might that be a security issue?

Comment: no I created it for testing, and some users too.I am trying to get how python works with json

Comment: You haven't given any sample of the data, so I can't give you an exact statement or query but to show you the direction, in case you would need to do more data manipulation after cleaning up your data, the usual solution is to convert your JSON to a Pandas DataFrame and the do all the queries on that data frame to find and cleanup your data.

    `import pandas as pd`
   ` df = pd.read_json('data.json')`

Now you have the ability to do all kinds of queries and manipulations and when you are finished you can save it 

    `df.to_json('new_data.json')`

Comment: {
      "id": "",
      "team_id": "",
      "name": "",
      "deleted": true,
      "profile": {
        "title": "",
        "phone": "",
        "skype": "",
        "real_name": "",
        "real_name_normalized": "",
        "display_name": "",
        "display_name_normalized": "",
        "status_text": "",
        "status_emoji": "", }  so I want to delete skype info

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with JSON, this will help you.

```
>>> j = json.loads('{"key":"value","key2":"value2"}')
>>> j
{'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> del j['key']
>>> j
{'key2': 'value2'}
```

Comment: Well I successes  so now I know how to delete keys, but how to delete values lets say I have  a key "profile " in profile I want to delete his skype  I get error KeyError: 'skype'

Comment: Can you please upload your example JSON data to [hastebin](https://hastebin.com) so I can better understand what do you really need to do?

Comment: Use: `del j["members"][0]["status_text"]`

Comment: Uh-oh... Sorry, my fault. Use `del j["members"][0]["profile"]["status_text"]`

Comment: Oh thank you so much that's interesting how you've done cuz I tried multidimensional loop.First loop for members  then for profile and then status text